# How to Avoid Duplicate Selection in Combinatorial Optimization Problems Using Genetic Algorithms

Tags: python, optimization, genetic-algorithm

**Abstracts**
I am currently developing a program that uses a genetic algorithm to solve a combinatorial optimization problem.
The objective is to select a control group of 2000 people from 5000 people with attribute values that are closest to the test group.
However, when I run the program, I am experiencing problems with the same person being selected multiple times.

**Issue Details**

- I am using the code below and it is not working as expected. Sometimes certain individuals are selected more than once.
- Attempts to solve the problem: Questions to ChatGPT, consulting an engineer who is not an algorithm expert.

**Goal we are trying to achieve**

- We want to find a way to prevent the same person from being selected multiple times.
- We are looking for a way to solve the problem without compromising computational efficiency.

**Question**

- How can I prevent the same person from being selected more than once in a program using a genetic algorithm?

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from deap import base, creator, tools, algorithms
import random
import time

# Dictionary of configuration variables
CONFIG = {
    "file_path": 'C:/Python用/test1_GENIE.csv', #File path of read data
    "population_size": 1000, 
    "generations": 100, 
    "cxpb": 0.5, 
    "mutpb": 0.2, 
    "n_control": 2000, 
    "pass_threshold": 0.05, 
    "output_path": 'outputpath' 
}

# File path
file_path = CONFIG["file_path"]

# data load
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# Separate data into test and control groups
test_group = data[data['is_test'] == 1]
control_group = data[data['is_test'] == 0]

# Calculation of mean value agreement for each column
def calculate_match_rates_vectorized(test_group, control_group, columns):
    # Calculate the mean of the test and control groups for each column
    means_test = test_group[columns].mean()
    means_control = control_group[columns].mean()

    # Replace zero values with smaller numbers to avoid dividing by zero
    means_control[means_control == 0] = np.finfo(float).eps

    # Calculation of Match Ratio
    match_rates = abs(1 - (means_test / means_control))
    return match_rates


# Calculation of the evaluation function
columns = data.columns[3:]

# Genetic Algorithm Parameters
POPULATION_SIZE = CONFIG["population_size"]
GENERATIONS = CONFIG["generations"]
CXPB = CONFIG["cxpb"]
MUTPB = CONFIG["mutpb"]
N_CONTROL = CONFIG["n_control"]

# objective function
def evaluate(individual):
    selected_control_group = control_group.iloc[individual]
    match_rates = calculate_match_rates_vectorized(test_group, selected_control_group, columns)
    max_match_rate = max(match_rates)
    return (max_match_rate,)


# Genetic Algorithm Initialization
creator.create("FitnessMin", base.Fitness, weights=(-1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMin)

toolbox = base.Toolbox()
toolbox.register("indices", random.sample, range(len(control_group)), N_CONTROL)
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initIterate, creator.Individual, toolbox.indices)
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)

toolbox.register("evaluate", evaluate)
toolbox.register("mate", tools.cxTwoPoint)
toolbox.register("mutate", tools.mutShuffleIndexes, indpb=0.05)
toolbox.register("select", tools.selTournament, tournsize=3)

# Record current time before algorithm execution
start_time = time.time()

# Running Genetic Algorithms
def main():
    random.seed(64)
    pop = toolbox.population(n=POPULATION_SIZE)
    hof = tools.HallOfFame(1)
    stats = tools.Statistics(lambda ind: ind.fitness.values)
    stats.register("avg", np.mean)
    stats.register("min", np.min)
    stats.register("max", np.max)

    pop, log = algorithms.eaSimple(pop, toolbox, cxpb=CXPB, mutpb=MUTPB, ngen=GENERATIONS, 
                                   stats=stats, halloffame=hof, verbose=True)

    # Record the time after the algorithm is executed and calculate the execution time
    end_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"run time: {elapsed_time} sec")
    
    # Output the index of the best individuals of the last generation to a CSV file
    best_individual = hof[0]
    best_control_group = control_group.iloc[best_individual]
    output_path = CONFIG["output_path"]
    best_control_group.to_csv(output_path, index=False)

    # Display of success message
    print(f"Data has been successfully saved. Save to: {output_path}")
    
    return pop, log, hof

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pop, log, hof = main()
```

Comment: You could use the knapsack example https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples/ga_knapsack.html and modify it for your needs. Using sets as individuals avoids duplicate persons. For the mate function, you can e. g. use the intersection of the parents for both children and then randomly select persons from the symmetric difference so that you end up with two children where their sets have the same count of persons as the parents.

Comment: Dear Michael Butscher,

Thank you very much for your helpful response to my question. Your suggestion to adapt the knapsack example from DEAP, using sets to avoid duplicates, and your advice on customizing the mate function are invaluable. I’m excited to apply your insights to my project.

I’ll start working on it based on your suggestions. Should I run into further issues or have questions, I hope you won’t mind if I reach out again.

Thanks again for your guidance and support.

Warm regards,